# Get string from arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

i get this query in php/mysql:

```
 $number=$_POST["number"];
 $sql="INSERT into tbl (number) values ('$number')";
 $sql="SELECT right (number,3) FROM tbl"; //where i get 234 from 1234.
```

Can i get the "right (number,3)" from the array, before update the database?

Thx

Comment: So you're trying to see what the value of `$number` is before you run the query?

Comment: You mean select the last number? so change order: first select then insert

Comment: Yes castis, before insert it, right from the array.

Answer (score 1):

To get the right three numbers from your variable [use `substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) -

```
$right = substr($number, -3);
```